# Get Desktop PIDL from Coordinates

Tags: c++, winapi, contextmenu, desktop, windows-shell

I'm trying to create functionality of the shell context menus despite them being blocked by a group policy for no real reason. One thing this demands is which icon the user is actually right-clicking, or if they are just clicking the desktop. The same thing also applies to explorer windows, although the desktop is where I'm planning on starting.

So far I can get the context menu to show for a specific file with a literal path. I found a nice list of interfaces on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774328), but none of the desktop-related ones I could find had any way of getting the desktop item like this. The closest match I could find was [IActiveDesktop::GetDesktopItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776349) with going through every single item and seeing whether the position matches, and then assuming none were clicked if none match.

This approach brings up two new issues, though. Firstly, I'm not sure how to go through every icon. Secondly, I have no clue how to convert this to a PIDL.

Also, even if I got the icons working, how would I extend this to the shell context menu for just the desktop?

Here's the code I use for a specific file:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP //going to be using on XP, tested on 7
#include <windows.h> //main header
#include <shellapi.h> //shell headers
#include <shlobj.h>

#include "G:\programming\v1\winwrap.h" //used for the window to display menu on

LPCONTEXTMENU cm; //holds context menu

msgproc (rproc) //this is called when right mouse button is depressed on window
{
    //This function shows the context menu of the program on this window
    //hwnd() is the HWND of the window involved with the right click
    HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu(); 
    DWORD Flags = CMF_EXPLORE;
    cm->QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, 0x7FFF, Flags);

    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    int Cmd = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hwnd(), 0);

    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO ci;

    if (Cmd)
    {
        ci.lpVerb = MAKEINTRESOURCE(Cmd - 1);
        ci.lpParameters = "";
        ci.lpDirectory = "";
        ci.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
        cm->InvokeCommand(&ci);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Window win; //create window for menu to go on, can be invisible, fullscreen later
    win.addmsg (WM_RBUTTONUP, rproc); //handle message with previous function

    WCHAR fname [MAX_PATH] = L"C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\context.exe"; //full path
    WCHAR path [MAX_PATH] = L"C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop"; //path part
    WCHAR name [MAX_PATH] = L"context.exe"; //filename part

    LPSHELLFOLDER desktopFolder; //get desktop shell folder
    SHGetDesktopFolder (&desktopFolder);

    LPITEMIDLIST pidl; //tried using this for no icon by changing GetUIObjectOf to this pild to no avail
    DWORD eaten;

    desktopFolder->ParseDisplayName (0, 0, path, &eaten, &pidl, 0);

    LPSHELLFOLDER parent;
    desktopFolder->BindToObject (pidl, 0, IID_IShellFolder, (void **)&parent);

    LPITEMIDLIST localPidl; //file pidl
    parent->ParseDisplayName (0, 0, name, &eaten, &localPidl, 0);

    parent->GetUIObjectOf (0, 0, (LPCITEMIDLIST *)&localPidl, IID_IContextMenu, 0, (void **)&cm); //gets context menu

    messageLoop(); //window message loop
}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: If the group policy is for no real reason, then you should ask your administrator to remove it, rather than trying to bypass the policy (which is probably a violation of your workplace policies).

Comment: It's a school, actually. I actually did try to ask the school IT person about it and she knows nothing at all. Students' opinions are worth nothing too. As for bypassing the policies, that's not a problem. On a relevant note, if I choose an option like "open" from the menu I have in place for one program on the desktop, the program doing the menu stuff crashes. I didn't jot down the code, but could the policy be the reason for this? Some of them (like copy) don't crash it though.

Comment: For any future visitors, [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160530-00/?p=93535) came up today. It's probably relevant, or at least a good start if you have this problem. Long gone are the days of not being able to right click things for me.